# Selenium python issues with switching between tabs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import time

N=22
while N<23:
    driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.get("https://www.totalcorner.com/league/view/1/page:22")
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    odds = {"Name":[],
            "Over":[],
            "Under":[]
            }
    done="No"
    n=0
    while done == "No":
        n += 1
        try:
            check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[{}]".format(n))
        except:
            print("error")
            done = "Yes"
            break
        
        check_if_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[{}]/td[1]".format(n))
        check_if_date = check_if_date.text
        
        if '201' not in check_if_date:
            button_odds = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[{}]/td[15]/a[1]/button".format(n))
            #open the new tab
            button_odds.click() 
            time.sleep(5)
            
            #here is the problem 
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            
            print("switched")
            time.sleep(5)
    
            odds_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[3]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]")
            odds_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[3]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]")
            odds_under = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[3]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[3]")
            name = odds_name.text
            name = name.split('(')[1]
            name = name.split(')')[0]
            over = odds_over.text
            over = over.split("@")[1]
            under = odds_under.text
            under = under.split("@")[1]
            odds["Name"].append(name)
            odds["Over"].append(over)
            odds["Under"].append(under)
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            
    N += 1
```

The first issue I encountered was that when opening the new tab selenium was still working on the first tab. To solve this I used

```
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

However this doesn't work either.
The issue is that sometimes, it seems randomly, selenium won't switch tabs the first time.

Comment: I found that relying on the new tab being at index -1 is not guaranteed.